# on pressing the cancel button of a todo list item, it removes all the below to-do list items, here is the code of my to-do list

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my HTML and JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>2-d0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>2-D0</h2>
    <div id="heading">
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
    <button id="button">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="lists">
        
    </div>

    <script src="functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Javascript code

```
'use strict'

const buttonclick = document.getElementById('button')
const list = document.getElementById('lists')
const a = "<span><button class = 'rbutton'>X</button></span>"   //list-item button


const clickhandler = () => {
    const text = document.getElementById('text')

    //creating a list element
    if(text.value != ''){
        let Newdiv = document.createElement('div')

        // appending elements
        Newdiv.innerHTML = text.value + a
        list.appendChild(Newdiv)

        let b = document.getElementsByClassName('rbutton')
        if(b !=[]){
            for(let i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
                b[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                    b[i].parentElement.parentElement.remove();
                    console.log(b)
                })
            }
        }
        

        //reseting the textarea value
        text.value = ''
}
}




buttonclick.addEventListener('click', clickhandler)
```

An error in shown on delete a item:  Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement. .
Can someone please explain what is wrong in my code and what does the error mean.
thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every click of the button you are attaching event handlers to the whole group again.
On the first iteration, 1st button has one delete handler.
On second iteration, 1st button has 2 event handler(one for buttons[0] and one for buttons[1]), and 2nd has one.
So on.

Use `this`. It will always point to the element to the event on which the event handler is attached:

```
this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `window.event.target.parentElement...` to get the button instead of `b[i].parentElement...`.

```js
        "use strict";

        const buttonclick = document.getElementById('button');
        const list = document.getElementById('lists');
        const a = "<span><button class = 'rbutton'>X</button></span>";   //list-item button


        const clickhandler = () => {
            const text = document.getElementById('text');

            //creating a list element
            if(text.value != '') {
                let Newdiv = document.createElement('div');

                // appending elements
                Newdiv.innerHTML = text.value + a;
                list.appendChild(Newdiv);

                let b = document.getElementsByClassName('rbutton');
                for(let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                    b[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                        window.event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
                    });
                }
                

                //reseting the textarea value
                text.value = '';
        }
        }




        buttonclick.addEventListener('click', clickhandler);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>2-d0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>2-D0</h2>
    <div id="heading">
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
    <button id="button">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="lists">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to simply use `this.parentElement.parentElement.remove()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>2-d0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>2-D0</h2>
    <div id="heading">
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
    <button id="button">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="lists">
        
    </div>

    <script>
        "use strict";

        const buttonclick = document.getElementById('button');
        const list = document.getElementById('lists');
        const a = "<span><button class = 'rbutton'>X</button></span>";   //list-item button


        const clickhandler = () => {
            const text = document.getElementById('text');

            //creating a list element
            if(text.value != '') {
                let Newdiv = document.createElement('div');

                // appending elements
                Newdiv.innerHTML = text.value + a;
                list.appendChild(Newdiv);

                let b = document.getElementsByClassName('rbutton');
                for(let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                    b[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                        this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
                    });
                }
                

                //reseting the textarea value
                text.value = '';
        }
        }




        buttonclick.addEventListener('click', clickhandler);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```